# Installing Data-Migration-Tool with Composer: git not found error

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2-migration-tool, git

when I try to install the Data-Migration-Tool with **Composer**:

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.2
```

I get the RuntimeException:

```
Failed to clone https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
```

I have git installed. Git commands like *git --help* is working.
The exec-path is correct. 
The **composer.json** file has the correct path:

```
"repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "data-migration-tool": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool"
        }
    },
```

In addition I created a **auth.json** file:

```
{
   "http-basic": {
       "repo.magento.com": {
           "username": "c7d...",
           "password": "0d3..."
       }
   },
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "778..."
   }
}
```

But I get still this error.

Comment: did you try using `git@github.com:magento/data-migration-tool.git` as url? that might make a difference...

Comment: Its also not working. I tried to reinstall composer and git but no difference. So next try is to install data-migration-tool manually with file copy. I hope this works.

Comment: Solved! PHP 7.0 was the problem. PHP 5.6 is working fine.

Comment: Is there any other way to resolve this error using PHP 7.0