# Installing Magento2 Data-Migration-Tool manual without composer

Tags: installation, magento2-migration-tool, command-line

How can I install the magento2 **data-migration-tool** manual **without** composer?

Already I copied the complete "data-migration-tool"-folder in *vendor/magento*. When I try to use migrate commands (ex. "migrate:settings"...) in magento root folder, I get the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.
```

I forgot something?

For the question why I want to install without composer.
See here: [Installing Data-Migration-Tool with Composer: git not found error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/113160/38778)

Comment: have you solved it

Answer (score 2):

In case you run into this problem, check if your magento binary is working alright by running:
`bin/magento --version`
That should output the version number, but in my case it showed errors related to folder and file permissions. After running:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod +x bin/magento
```

the magento binary was working fine and so was the migration command.